# Please give an example of a compact operator which satisfies these conditions

Tags: functional-analysis

Please give an example of a compact operator in a Banach space. The compact operator satisfies the following conditions:$\sigma_c(A)=\sigma(A)=\{0\}$. Here A
 is  a compact operator, $\sigma(A)$ means the set of spectrum of A, and $\sigma_c(A)$ means the set of continuous spectrum of A.

Answer (score 2):

The Volterra operator will do the job https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator